# Joining two queries into one query or making a sub-query

Tags: sql

I am having some trouble with the following queries originally done for some Access forms:

```
SELECT qry1.TCKYEAR AS Yr, COUNT(qry1.SID) AS STUDID, qry1.SID AS MID, table_tckt.tckt_tick_no 
FROM table_tckt INNER JOIN qry1 ON table_tckt.tckt_SID = qry1.SID
GROUP BY qry1.TCKYEAR, qry1.SID, table_tckt.tckt_tick_no 
HAVING (((table_tckt.tick_no)=[forms]![frmNAME]![cboNAME]));

SELECT table_tckt.sid, FORMAT([tckt_iss_date], 'yyyy') AS TCKYEAR, table_tckt.tckt_tick_no, table_tckt.licstate
FROM table_tckt
WHERE (((table_tckt.licstate)<>"NA"));
```

I am no longer working with Access, but JSP for the forms. I need to somehow either combine these two queries into one query or find another way to have a query 'query' another one.

Comment: Any help woul dbe greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following would be the quickest way to do it in SQL Server. I don't know what you are using as a backend but maybe it will point you in the right direction.

It basically uses the statement within the with {} to create an in memory table named sql1 that you can query.

```
with 
 {
 SELECT table_tckt.sid, 
    FORMAT([tckt_iss_date], 'yyyy') AS TCKYEAR,
    table_tckt.tckt_tick_no, 
    table_tckt.licstate
FROM table_tckt
WHERE (((table_tckt.licstate)<>"NA"));
  } as sql1
 SELECT qry1.TCKYEAR AS Yr, 
    COUNT(qry1.SID) AS STUDID, 
    qry1.SID AS MID, 
    table_tckt.tckt_tick_no 
 FROM table_tckt 
INNER JOIN qry1 ON table_tckt.tckt_SID = qry1.SID
GROUP BY qry1.TCKYEAR, qry1.SID, table_tckt.tckt_tick_no 
HAVING (((table_tckt.tick_no)=@YourVariable));
```

Comment: That sure worked, the only thing I changed was the {} to ().
Thank you very much